# MySQL : DATE_FORMAT() vs. SUBSTR()

Tags: mysql, statistics, date-format

I'm currently working on MYSQL DB optimizations. I'm looking around some slow queries and I try to optimize some of them.

In my app, for statistics purposes, I'm querying and -very- big table (millions of records) which contains visitors log entries (clicks, opens, impressions,...).
That table contains :

- `ID` (`INT`, `Primary Key`)
- `OpenDate` (`DATETIME`)
- `ListID` (`INT`)
- `UserID` (`INT`)
- ...and some other fields

I need to retrieve number of rows per Day. So I need to convert DATETIME into DATE to be able to GROUP BY day value.

- `DATETIME` is on format yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss
- In the facts, what I need is the only 10 first chars : yyyy-mm-dd

Currently, the query is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalOpens, DATE_FORMAT(OpenDate,  '%Y-%m-%d') AS DayOfWeek 
FROM `stats_open` WHERE ListID='38' AND UserID='4'
GROUP BY crc32(DayOfWeek) ORDER BY TotalOpens DESC
```

But I wonder if I should change the DATE_FORMAT function to SUBSTR() function, so MySQL would work a little bit less ?
Isnt easier for MySQL to cut a string instead of reformat a date ?

Thanks for your help.

Joffrey

Comment: What is the type of `OpenDate`? If it is `datetime` or `timestamp`, you can simply `GROUP BY date(OpenDate)`

Comment: Oh ? Really ? Yes, `OpenDate` a a `DATETIME` field.

Comment: Off course. No need for DATE_FORMAT. And what is that `crc32()` for? Why do you use it?

Comment: I guess `CRC32` is useful for converting value to `INT` values. So it make the `GROUP BY` easier for MySQL. I'm not sure because this query has been written by antoher dev.

Comment: The GROUP BY is not easier for integers than dates. Even if it was a bit easier, calling a function (crc32()) as many times as the rows to be grouped (or the rows of the table) is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `OpenDate` is a `datetime` column, you don't need to use `DATE_FORMAT()`, you can simply `GROUP BY DATE(OpenDate)`. And the extra `CRC32()` call seem completely redundant.

The query can be rewritten:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalOpens, 
       DATE(OpenDate) AS DayOfWeek 
FROM stats_open 
WHERE ListID = 38 
  AND UserID = 4
GROUP BY DATE(OpenDate) 
ORDER BY TotalOpens DESC ;
```

Add an index on `(ListID, UserID, OpenDate)`, to make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks ! So `DATE()` will use less resources than `DATE_FORMAT()` ?

Comment: Probably a bit less. Not much but yes, less. Removing the crc32() calls will be another gain. Adding the index much better. How long does the query takes now?

Comment: OK thank you so much, I'm gonna try it. Now, the query takes up to 60seconds...

Comment: The index would help, even your existing query.

Comment: OK thank you. I just another question about index in my case : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193513/mysql-mariadb-many-indexes-vs-one-multi-column-index :-)